# Take a part of a string (PHP)

Tags: php, string

We are trying to get certain parts of a String.

We have the string:

`location:32:DaD+LoC:102AD:Ammount:294`

And we would like to put the information in different strings. For example `$location=32` and `$Dad+Loc=102AD`

The values vary per string but it will always have this construction:
`location:{number}:DaD+LoC:{code}:Ammount:{number}`

So... how do we get those values?

Comment: http://php.net/explode can do the thing if you have basic syntax knowledge. Also, whole http://php.net/strings page is very useful reading, at least to make a picture of what PHP can do with strings

Comment: Note that you cannot have a variable named `$DaD+LoC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fast forward approach:

```
$string = "location:32:DaD+LoC:102AD:Ammount:294";

$arr = explode(":",$string);

$location= $arr[1];
$DaD_LoC= $arr[3];
$Ammount= $arr[5];
```

Answer (score 3):

That would produce what you want, but for example $dad+Loc is an invalid variable name in PHP so it wont work the way you want it, better work with an array or an stdClass Object instead of single variables.

```
  $string = "location:32:DaD+LoC:102AD:Ammount:294";
  $stringParts = explode(":",$string);
  $variableHolder = array();
  for($i = 0;$i <= count($stringParts);$i = $i+2){
      ${$stringParts[$i]} = $stringParts[$i+1];
  }

  var_dump($location,$DaD+LoC,$Ammount);
```

Comment: @thomasmalt care to run this "good" code ans see how it works?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel as i state THIS is an imperfect Solution, BUT it is the correct solution for the Problem he described, to get a variable $Dad+Loc containing the Value 102AD, but like i said you can't access the Variable since its bad formed, so He has to think again about what he wants to archive. I prefer to show People the right way and even theyr mistakes ... not spoon-feed them

Answer (score 2):

$StringArray = explode ( ":"  , $string)

Answer (score 2):

By using preg_split and mapping the resulting array into an associative one.
Like this:

```
$str  = 'location:32:DaD+LoC:102AD:Ammount:294';
$list = preg_split('/:/', $str);

$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i = $i+2) {
    $result[$array[$i]] = $array[$i+1];
};

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

the php function split is deprecated so instead of this it is recommended to use preg_split or explode.
very useful in this case is the function list():

```
list($location, $Dad_Loc, $ammount) = explode(':', $string);
```

EDIT:
my code has an error:

```
list(,$location,, $Dad_Loc,, $ammount) = explode(':', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems nobody can do it properly

```
$string = "location:32:DaD+LoC:102AD:Ammount:294";
list(,$location,, $dadloc,,$amount) = explode(':', $string);
```